Unable to add collection to chromadb, is there anyway to add the collection to the chromadb
Body:
Problem:
I am trying to add collections to ChromaDB using the code below, but the process seems to exit before reaching the line collection.add(embeddings=[item["embedding"]], ids=[item["id"]]). I've added multiple try-except blocks to isolate the issue, but I am still unable to determine what's going wrong.
What I've tried:
I confirmed that the ChromaDB client initializes correctly, and the collection is either created or retrieved successfully.
The issue seems to occur right before or during the attempt to add embeddings.
I attempted to add more exception handling to catch errors, but the process seems to halt without triggering any exceptions.
Here’s my code:
import chromadb

print("Initializing ChromaDB client...")
try:
    client = chromadb.Client()
    print("ChromaDB client initialized.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error initializing ChromaDB client: {e}")

try:
    print("Creating or getting collection 'feic'...")
    collection = client.create_collection(name="feic")
    print("Collection created or retrieved.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error creating/retrieving collection: {e}")

embeddings = [
    {"id": "face_1", "embedding": [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]},  # Example embedding values
    {"id": "face_2", "embedding": [0.4, 0.5, 0.6]},
]

try:
    print("Storing embeddings...")
    for item in embeddings:
        print(f"Adding embedding: {item['id']}, values: {item['embedding']}")
        collection.add(embeddings=[item["embedding"]], ids=[item["id"]])
    print("Embeddings stored successfully!")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error adding embeddings: {e}")

try:
    print("Fetching stored embeddings...")
    results = collection.get(include=['embeddings'])
    print("Retrieved embeddings:", results)
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error retrieving embeddings: {e}")

Output:
Initializing ChromaDB client...
ChromaDB client initialized.
Creating or getting collection 'feic'...
Collection created or retrieved.
Storing embeddings...
Adding embedding: face_1, values: [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]

output of my pip freeze:

